# Jetty Websockets can't connect to server

Tags: websocket, jetty, localhost

So I have correctly setup a jetty (eclipse based) server listening on 8080. (i put a little hello world html to test). So if I go to

```
http://localhost:8080/index.html
```

my html is displayed.

Now I have followed this tutorial, to work with Websockets.

```
https://gist.github.com/manzke/1021982
```

the web.xml is configured as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>tailor</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>WebSocket</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.sample.websocket.ChatWebSocketServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WebSocket</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jetty-test/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

To connect to my Websocket I use the following url:

```
ws://localhost:8080/jetty-test/servlet/WebSocket
```

But when I click on "Connect" nothing happend ?, The connect doesn't seems to establish..

Am I missing something? Or is the url that is wrong?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web.xml is wrong, replace

```
<url-pattern>/jetty-test/*</url-pattern>
```

by

```
<url-pattern>/servlet/*</url-pattern>
```